# ASM and ORACLE switching environments?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I've just installed ASM and try to change environment using this commands but its not working

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Did you installed it properly? May be you missed something...

2)Check your .bash_profile file. It is a hidden file stored in oracle users’ home directory /home/oracle

3)You have a lot of mistakes try this
change root to oracle:

```
su - oracle
then try this commands
export ORACLE_SID=+ASM
export ORAENV_ASK=NO
. oraenv
```

and then check with this command: which sqlplus
If its not working reboot it.